# The meaning of no representation of uncertainty in Maximum Likelihood Estimation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, descriptive-statistics, expectation-maximization

I was looking at a youtube video for Maximum Likelihood Estimation. The lecturer said Maximum Likelihood Estimation doesn't have any representation of uncertainty, which I didn't really get. Can somebody explain what it means?

Comment: Could you provide a reference to the video (e.g. name of the lecturer, link etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the MLE is a [point estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_estimation), which does not indicate how accurate this estimation is. In order to quantify uncertainty about the estimation using MLE, you need to use [interval estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_estimation) such as confidence intervals or profile likelihood intervals.